# How to change cell's ComboBox style in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: .net, datagridview

Cells in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn have ComboBoxStyle DropDownList. It means the user can only select values from the dropdown. The underlying control is ComboBox, so it can have style DropDown. How do I change the style of the underlying combo box in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. Or, more general, can I have a column in DataGridView with dropdown where user can type?

Answer (score 5):

```
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
    {
        DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl cbo = 
            e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
        cbo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
    }
}
```

[Problem with combobox and databound datagridview](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=13855&SiteID=1)

Comment: This is only idea of the solution. Complete solution requires validation routine, otherwise DataGridView will throw an exception. Useful solution also often requires cell specific list in dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

Following solution works for me

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == Column1.Index) 
    {
        // Add the value to column's Items to pass validation
        if (!Column1.Items.Contains(e.FormattedValue.ToString())) 
        {
            Column1.Items.Add(e.FormattedValue);
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = 
                e.FormattedValue;
        }
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e) 
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == Column1.Index) 
    {
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)e.Control;
        if (cb != null) 
        {
            cb.Items.Clear();
            // Customize content of the dropdown list
            cb.Items.AddRange(appropriateCollectionOfStrings);
            cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the given if condition always turns out to be true in my databounded combobox...
is there a work around...

given condition:
===================================================================
if (!Column1.Items.Contains(e.FormattedValue.ToString())) {
                                                Column1.Items.Add(e.FormattedValue);
                                                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = e.FormattedValue;
                                        }

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!Column1.Items.Contains(e.FormattedValue.ToString())) { 
    Column1.Items.Add(e.FormattedValue);     
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = e.FormattedValue; 
}
```

may always return true because 
`Column1.Items.Contains()`
is searching for `String` values. 
if `e.FormattedValue` is not a `String` then the comparison will fail.

try

```
if (!Column1.Items.Contains(e.FormattedValue.ToString())) { 
    Column1.Items.Add(e.FormattedValue.ToString());     
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = e.FormattedValue.ToString(); 
}
```

or

```
if (!Column1.Items.Contains(e.FormattedValue)) { 
    Column1.Items.Add(e.FormattedValue); 
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = e.FormattedValue; 
}
```