# Is it possible to have a column in a DataGridView that works as a ComboBox that allows user to enter a new value?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I know that in a normal `ComboBox`, if the `FlatStyle` is `Standard`, the user will be able to type a value that is not in the `Items` list. But if a combo box in a `DataGridView` is `Standard`, it won't let me type a new value. Is it possible to achieve this functionality in a column in a `DataGridView`?

Comment: You may want to take a look at using the DataRepeater control. The DataGridView control seems to be designed for viewing data. If you want the users to control the data then the DataRepeater is probably the way you want to go.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change cell's ComboBox style in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202084/how-to-change-cells-combobox-style-in-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in a DataGridView, you can add a column of `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` type. It's `DisplayStyle` and/or `FlatStyle` are dependent on the current row state. I think when you add a new row (edit mode), you are able to add values to it.

References:
[Add items to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in DataGridView during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357389/add-items-to-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-in-datagridview-during-runtime)
http://www.lazycoder.com/weblog/2006/09/12/adding-values-to-the-datagridviewcomboboxcell-at-runtime/

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void dataGridView2_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (dataGrid_ItemsList.Columns[dataGrid_ItemsList.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex].HeaderText)
            {
                case "Batch":
                    if (e.Control is ComboBox)
                    {
                        ComboBox _with1 = (ComboBox)e.Control;
                        _with1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                        _with1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                        _with1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                        _with1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = BatchList;
                        //_with1.Validating -= HandleComboBoxValidating;
                        //_with1.Validating += HandleComboBoxValidating;

                        _with1.Validating += (ss, ee) =>
                        {
                            if (!_with1.Items.Contains(_with1.Text))
                            {
                                var comboColumn = dataGrid_ItemsList.CurrentCell as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
                                _with1.Items.Add(_with1.Text);
                                _with1.Text = _with1.Text;
                                comboColumn.Items.Add(_with1.Text);
                                this.dataGrid_ItemsList.CurrentCell.Value = _with1.Text;
                            }
                        };
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _CommonClasses._Cls_ExceptionsHandler.HandleException(ex,false);
        }
    }
```