# How set property DropDownStyle

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0

I create in DataGridView column DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.
I need set style DropDown.

```
this.combobox.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

how do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change cell's ComboBox style in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202084/how-to-change-cells-combobox-style-in-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn)

Answer (score 2):

Use [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.FlatStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.flatstyle.aspx). The `FlatStyle` property affects the behavior and appearance of the drop-down arrows for the cells in this column.

```
dataGridViewComboBoxColumn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

Comment: Hope that the one that vote down the answer has an explanation for that. Hope he has the courage to tell me about it as well !!

Comment: I'll not put a minus. But this is not what you need.

Comment: @simply denis: What does he needs ? I do not see any other answers !!

Comment: Look at the beginning of what makes ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

Comment: @simply denis: It looks ambigious to me. Would you please provide an answer ?

Comment: Visual style should not be changed